Decrypt Java produced AES file with openssl
The following Java produces encryoted data:
  private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
  private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;

  public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secretKey, String salt) {

    try {

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);

        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] encryptedData = new byte[iv.length + cipherText.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedData, 0, iv.length);
        System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, encryptedData, iv.length, cipherText.length);

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle the exception properly
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }


Running this as follows:
encrypt( "Hello, this is a secret message.", "MySecretKey", "MySalt");
Gives the result:
zYsUELxuE3KT4IDa1cbRnX70OSlQTbcDa1LEuh0IzfjZZcJhnuX8kLFcGqYLWjfp0XJzfgwFreZIqmqE1HqlGw==
I save this to a file, and now would like to use openssl to decrypt it.
I have used a variety of options with openssl but I cannot seem to get it to work, e.g.:
 echo -n MySalt | od -A n -t x1 | perl -lpe's,\s+,,g'
4d7953616c74

openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -k MySecretKey -S 4d7953616c74  -md sha256 -in file.in
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.

openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -k MySecretKey -S 4d7953616c74 -iter 65536 -md sha256 -in file.in
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
z....garbage..........


I cannot find the right combination of options for openssl .

(Not programming or development)
First, enc -e (or default) is encrypt; -d is decrypt. Also, enc expects (and puts) the salt at the beginning of the file, but does not expect (or put) the IV, and by default it does not do PBKDF2 and derives the IV in addition to the key. And only 3.2.0 up (i.e. released in last few months) can use a salt length other than the traditional 8. But everything since 1.1.0 in 2016 defaults to SHA256 for the hash.
So if you have 3.2.0 up:
$ echo zYsUELxuE3KT4IDa1cbRnX70OSlQTbcDa1LEuh0IzfjZZcJhnuX8kLFcGqYLWjfp0XJzfgwFreZIqmqE1HqlGw== | \
> openssl base64 -d -A >78319330.bin
$ iv=$( head -c16 78319330.bin |xxd -p ) # or if no xxd, something like your od+sed
$ ( printf Salted__MySalt; tail -c+17 78319330.bin ) | \
> openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k MySecretKey -pbkdf2 -iter 65536 -saltlen 6 -iv $iv
Hello, this is a secret message.


I'm new to this as well, and out of curiosity and surprise, it seems that the salt can be extracted from the file itself, so how does having the salt that make it more secure than just the key/password?

Thanks this worked for the example above, but I have a problem trying to adopt this for encrypting a binary/zip file for which I will post a separate question.

@ProWest: salt blocks an attacker from precomputing one dictionary, or rainbow table, to attack multiple hashes, such as the passwords of millions of users at once, or detecting duplicated passwords among such populations; it does not need to be secret, and usually is not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) or crypto.stackexchange.com .
